# Is there a way to make multiple adjacencies explicit using the Polygon Neighbors tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

I am analyzing a shapefile of precincts (polygons) in ArcMap 10.6.1 and used the **Polygon Neighbors Tool** to generate a table denoting the neighbor relationship between polygons. I am using the field **PSN** (Precinct Serial Number) to uniquely identify polygons. The neighbor list appears in the following format, with **LENGTH** being the length of the shared perimeter in meters and **NODE_COUNT** indicating whether the neighbor touches only at a point. The neighbor list goes both ways; so if 533 and 534 are neighbors, there are instances of both precincts showing up in the src_PSN field as seen below.

[image: Example of the Precinct Neighbor List generated by the Polygon Neighbors Tool]

In my map, I have several (I'm unsure of how many) **multi-adjacent polygons**; in other words, polygons that touch their neighbors in two places. For example, here is one instance in my map. The two highlighted polygons, 533 and 538, have this multi-adjacency.

[image: Example of two polygons which are adjacent to one another in multiple places]

Is there a way to make multi-adjacencies show up as two separate records?

In the example above, polygon 533 would have 11 neighbor records rather than 10. I need the multi-adjacency to be explicit in my table in order to run a bit of code I've been handed to run an analysis on the map.

Comment: You'll probably need to [convert your polygons to lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/polygon-to-line.htm) in order to identify multiple adjacencies.

Comment: Ahh... yes, that makes sense, @Tom. I'll play around and see if I can somehow use the line data to do that. Thanks.